# Nginx returning 404 for files in directory, server root param is correct

Tags: linux, nginx

I'm trying to set up a directory to host static files. Whenever I try to access a file in the directory, I get a 404 error:

My config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        root /home/files;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ -404;
        }
}
```

When I go to mydomain.com, I get a 403 error, which I believe is expected as I have not set an `index` directive. When I try to go to a file that I have uploaded to the server in `/home/files/myfile.htm` by going to mydomain.com/myfile.htm, I get a 404 error. When I look at the error log, I see:

```
2020/03/09 10:27:10 [crit] 33550#0: *80 stat() "/home/files/test.htm" failed (13: Permission denied), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /test.htm HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.com"
2020/03/09 10:27:10 [error] 33550#0: *80 open() "/home/files-404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /test.htm HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.com"
```

The permission for the folder `files/` is 775, while the permission for `test.htm` is 644

NOTE: If I keep everything else the same but change the `root` directive to `/var/www/html/mydomain.com;` and move the file to that directory, it works.

Comment: That should be a `=404` and not `-404` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)). What are the permissions on `home`? Is this SELinux?

Comment: `home` is 755. SELinux is enabled, I have `httpd_enable_homedirs` and `httpd_read_user_content` set to `on`

Comment: If I keep everything else the same but change the root directive to `/var/www/html/mydomain.com;` and move the file to that directory, it works